# Magento2: change theme layout (columns)

Tags: magento2, layout, theme

I bought a theme for magento2 and I would like to change the layout for the homepage only.

It's currently a 2 columns layout and I want to completely remove the left column and have the main column with 100% width. Is it possible to do this for the homepage without affecting other pages ?

Here is the shop is that helps: https://schmuggler-shop.de/

Which files would I have to edit ?

Comment: go in admin and check in content > pages  edit  home page then check under Design section Layout filed should have 1column.

Comment: I just checked and its already set to 1 column

Comment: You website is already with 1column, if you need to change the other sections of that page then you need to take help from html developer.

Comment: I am a developer but I have zero experience with magento :p

Comment: yes, @SukumarGorai is right you need html developer or frontend developer.

Comment: Please share code which is in Content field.

Comment: The content is pretty much empty, this is all there is inside: <div class="page-content"><em style="display: none;">page-content</em></div>

Answer (score 0):

login into `admin panel > Content > pages > Choose homepage` edit that.

choose custom design use layout `1 column`.

see below screenshot.[image]